# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/nil/public_html/php/getuids.php on line 10

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I'm pretty new to PHP, and after typing up a few lines and testing I ran into an error that I have no idea on how to fix:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/nil/public_html/php/getuids.php on line 10

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("connection unsuccessful");
mysql_select_db("nil_chatModerators")

$query = "SELECT * FROM moderators";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;

mysql_close();

?>
```

Here's a screenshot of everything from phpMyAdmin:

(can't post images yet..) https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF0iW.png

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon missing in line 4. See my updated code

```
 <?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("connection unsuccessful");
    mysql_select_db("nil_chatModerators");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM moderators";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo $result;

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```